# Why does Java chop off the higher-order bits of this long?

Tags: java, types, casting, jvm, type-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
System.out.println(1 + 0xFFFFFFFFL);
System.out.println(1L + 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

The first line prints the expected value, `4294967296`.  But the second line prints a `0`.  I checked the type of both expressions (by passing them to methods) and both are recognized as `long` by the JVM. The Lava 7 language specification states that with binary operations, "if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long."  It seems that's what is happening, but I have two questions:

1. If both operands end up being longs, why are the higher-order bits chopped off in the first expression?
2. Why should the order matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0xFFFFFFFF` is equal to `-1`. When you add `1 + -1` you get 0.

The order matters because `0xFFFFFFFFL != (long) 0xFFFFFFFF`

Just like `(double) 0.1F != 0.1`

Comment: Thanks! I should have realized that.

Answer (score 1):

By default, in java all numeric constants are `int`.

In the second example, because java uses the [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representation, the expression `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1` as an `int`, which when widened to a `long` stays as `-1`, so you've coded `1 + -1`, giving zero.

Comment: True, but if both operands are explicitly `long`, and the result is `long`, why is the arithmetic wrong?

Comment: Ah, the ever-evolving, quick-but-approximate answer.